# Fetching data from large number of independent tables from DB using Entity Framework codefirst

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API. I need to fetch ~50 table data in a single request for some calculations. Since I am  fetching these many tables together my Web API response time is high. All the tables are independent. I am using repository pattern and EF code first approach. Any suggestions to improve the response time for the given scenario :

The code looks like below :

```
public static class FetchDataExtensions
{
    public static DbData GetData(this IRepository repo, Request request)
    {
        return new DbData
                   { 
                       // fetching data from db using repository pattern
                       Table1 = repo.GetTable1Data(request.name, request.gender),
                       Table2 = repo.GetTable2Data(request.gender),
                       Table3 = repo.GetTable3Data(),
                       ........
                       Table50 = repo.GetTable50Data()
                   };   
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
     private readonly DBContext context;

     public Repository(DBContext context)
     { 
          this.context = context;
     }

     public Table1 GetTable1Data(string name, string gender)
     { 
         try
         {
             return context.Table1.Single(a => a.Name.Equals(name.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                               && a.Gender.Equals(gender.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await threading concept. Where at a time multiple tread will read data and it will help you to minimize table reading time.

for refer [example of async-await][1]
[1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_asynchronous_query.htm

a part from that you can using indexing. See how to apply indexing on table in EF.

Comment: I already tried aync/await.. But was getting error : "a second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed"
To fix this error I used Await for each operation which resulted in delayed response time again.